# Too many lines and curves on the polynomial graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression, polynomials

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\MONSTER\\Desktop\\dosyalar\\datasets\\Auto.csv")
x = df["horsepower"].to_numpy()
y = df["mpg"].to_numpy()

x = x.reshape(-1,1)

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 5)
X_poly = poly.fit_transform(x)
poly.fit(X_poly,y)

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_poly, y)
y_pred = lr.predict(X_poly)

plt.scatter(x,y,color="blue",marker=".")
plt.plot(x,y_pred,color="red")
```

I have tried to draw a polynomial regression curve but I couldn't manage it. Someone told me to sorting values before plotting via "numpy.argsort" but nothing has changed. How can I fix it?

[image: Here is the result]

Comment: the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
I see nowhere in this code that you have sorted the regression coordinates; those *must* be in x-axis order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably scatter is better for you:

```
plt.scatter(x,y_pred,color="red")
```

Or with `argsort` as mentioned:

```
orders = np.argsort(x.ravel())

plt.plot(x[orders], y[orders], color='red')
```

Comment: Yeah, the error that you are talking about came up when I put "argsort", but why? How can I fix it? Scatter is looking much better but I do not want discrete dots  @BigBen

Comment: @BigBen how about now?