# Polynomial function in matplotlib displaying multiple lines

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am experiencing the same issue that is asked in this question: [Too many lines and curves on the polynomial graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63927400/too-many-lines-and-curves-on-the-polynomial-graph)

The solution for that issue seems to be sorting the points based on the x axis. In my case im pretty sure my data is already sorted as I am placing my x array into the plot like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,26,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,214,67,225,250,0,0,0,94,0,0,1366,137])
y = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0])
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
ax3.scatter(x, y)
ax3.plot(x, 0 + 0.004*x + 1.63e-06*(x**2), label='squared')
ax3.legend()
plt.show()
```

I would like to plot just the quadratic line:
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem from your example. If I fill in some values for x and y, I get dots and one line. Can you make sure to provide an example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Zorgoth Please try it now and let me know should show my issue

Comment: Zeros interspersed in your data clearly means it's not sorted, so I'm closing as a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example does indeed have unsorted data in the x axis, and the solution is just as in the question you linked:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,26,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,214,67,225,250,0,0,0,94,0,0,1366,137])
y = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0])
order = np.argsort(x)
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
ax3.scatter(x[order], y[order])
ax3.plot(x[order], 0 + 0.004*x[order] + 1.63e-06*(x[order]**2), label='squared')
ax3.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The `np.argsort(x)` did it for me. Thanks.